# Angular 6 Animations Not Working if Component Has a p element or any Div tags

Tags: angular

I recently started working with Angular and I am very new to animations. So I have been following a tutorial and it seems as though if I add the animation to my router module the animation will work but if I add any tags inside of the element within the router-outlet the animations do not work. Here is my code.

app.component.html

```
  <section id="content">
    <div [@FadeInAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
      <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </section>
```

fadein.ts

```
import {
  trigger,
  animate,
  transition,
  style,
  query, group
} from '@angular/animations';

export const FadeInAnimation = trigger('FadeInAnimation', [
  // The '* => *' will trigger the animation to change between any two states
  transition('* => *', [
    // The query function has three params.
    // First is the event, so this will apply on entering or when the element is added to the DOM.
    // Second is a list of styles or animations to apply.
    // Third we add a config object with optional set to true, this is to signal
    // angular that the animation may not apply as it may or may not be in the DOM.
    query(
      ':enter',
      [style({ opacity: 0 })],
      { optional: true }
    ),
    query(
      ':leave',
      // here we apply a style and use the animate function to apply the style over 0.3 seconds
      [style({ opacity: 1 }), animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 0 }))],
      { optional: true }
    ),
    query(
      ':enter',
      [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))],
      { optional: true }
    )
  ])
]);
```

So if I add the following into home.component.html

```
 home works!
```

the fade in animation will work. However if I add:

```
<p>  home works!</p>
```

or

```
<div>   home works!</div>
```

it does not work

Any idea why this may be happening? Thanks in advance for any hep provided.

--EDIT--

Here is the home.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FadeInAnimation} from "../../animations/FadeIn";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  // make fade in animation available to this component
  animations: [FadeInAnimation],

  // attach the fade in animation to the host (root) element of this component
  host: { '[@FadeInAnimation]': '' }
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: It is not clear how you use home component, there is nothing about this component in your code. Please share more relevant code

Comment: The home.component.html has exactly the code I posted above but I am editing to share home.component.ts now. Not sure that's going to be much help as it is a default component which just gets loaded through the router.